# How to retrieve Hibernate 4 session factory if connection data is set in JPA's persistence.xml?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, sessionfactory

Is it possible to create or retrieve an Hibernate 4 session factory if the database connection is defined in JPA's `persistence.xml` rather than in `hibernate.cfg.xml`? If yes, how?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are a lot of info of this, for example you can use this:

```
org.hibernate.Session session = (Session)entityManager.getDelegate();
```

Source:

[source](http://bill.burkecentral.com/2007/07/06/co-existence-with-hibernate-jpa-and-ejb3/)

Comment: The answer here does not relate to 'create or retrieve a Hibernate 4 Session Factory' instead it shows how to get a Session object from an EntityManager. Maybe this was ultimately what the asker wanted to know, but strictly by the language of the question it is wrong. The linked article itself only goes to explain how to use hibernate.cfg.xml as part of the configuration of a persistence.xml, and not how to get a SessionFactory with just a persistence.xml. I think the answer should be re-written